# Maintaining additional features on top of an (upstream) open-source project

Tags: git, version-control, open-source

At my job, we've used open source software for some of our products and have developed some additional features and capabilities on top of what the main-line project offers.  The open-source project is being actively developed, and I intend to contribute some of these changes back to the main-line open-source project.

However, I've also added some other features that are required for our products.  These features have security implications which are perfectly acceptable for my use case, but not acceptable in general.  Thus, the open-source project will never accept those features as part of the main-line development, so I'll have to maintain those features myself.

I'd like the ability to occasionally take new releases of the main-line development, but it seems this will require me to "re-patch" my locally-maintained features into the main-line every so often.

How can I maintain the features I need as a separate line of development from the main line with minimum overhead?  I'd like to avoid having to rewrite the locally-maintained features every time something changes in the main-line project, but I'd prefer not to "fork" the entire project as I'd like to continue to contribute patches and pull updates from the main-line.

Would it be best to maintain my own set of "patch" files that implement my separate features (where I attempt to apply those patches) to future releases of the main-line project?  (Note: The open-source project uses git for revision control, if there are any tools for git that help with this.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use topic branches. When you're coding, make sure that code you can contribute back to the project lives in different topic branches than code required for your specific implementation. Privately, for your employer, merge all of them into `master` to make your software work. Publicly, only publish and pull-request (or patch via email or whatever the project does) the ones that don't contain your site-specific code.

There's nothing unusual with that workflow at all. Topic branches, aka feature branches, are also a good git habit; the workflow will have other perks.